# issueFieldMatch returns no results

Tags: jira, jql

If I search for:

```
project=cp and summary ~ "Bridge"
```

I get 52 results. However, if I search for:

```
issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("project=CP", "summary", "Bridge")
```

I get 0 results.

I don't have admin access, so I can't look at the logs to try to debug this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check and compare the issues that are found by the first query. Do they really contain "Bridge" word?

There are two things that might affect your search of the latter query:

- **stemming** -- `summary ~ Bridge` can find all issues using "bridging" while the latter query not
- **case sensitivity** -- please note that the latter query is case sensitive and won't find summaries with "bridge"

To search summaries in case insensitive way, use this instead:

```
issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("project=CP", "summary", "(?i)Bridge")
```

Comment: I checked again, the first query definitely returns results with 'Bridge' (with a capital B). Still 0 results with your case-insensitive issueFunction query :(

Comment: Well, hard to say. Try the field with `"Summary"` or without quotes (`summary`). If it doesn't help, reach your Jira administrator and check if ScriptRunner is updated. They may also try to run indexing of your CP project (but if there's anything wrong with data, the first query wouldn't work either). And you can also try to reach ScriptRunner technical support for deeper assistance (it might require cooperation with your Jira administrator).

Comment: All searches returned empty with all variations on "Summary" (lower case, quotes, etc.). I'll have to contact the admins :(. Thanks for looking!